# Missing required parameters for in a Update Form Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've been working on a webapp recently in laravel and i wanted to have a eddit function within tthe application. but im getting this error Missing required parameters for [Route: producten.update] [URI: producten/{producten}], and i dont know what i've done wrong.

This is the Routes im using:

```
Route::resource('producten', 'ProductenController', ['only' => ['index', 'store', 'update', 'delete', 'edit', 'destroy', 'create']]);
```

This is the controller function im using for showing the edit page and updating.

The Edit function

```
public function edit(Request $request, Product $product)
{
   // $product = Product::FindorFail($id);
    // Product is a table with all products, with sellprice and buy price
    // fabriek = table that has a foreign key attached to the product table
    return view('producten.edit', [
        'model' => $product,
        'fabrieks' => Fabriek::lists('Id')
        ]);

}
```

The Update Function:

```
public function update(Request $request, Product $product)
    {

        $product->update($request->all());

        return redirect(Route('producten.index'));

    }
```

and this is the view i use for it.

```
    {{Form::model($model, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => 'ProductenController@update', $model ]) }}

    {{ Form::label('naam:')}}
    {{ Form::text('naam') }} <br>

    {{ Form::label('inkoopPrijs:')}}
    {{ Form::text('inkoopPrijs') }} <br>

    {{ Form::label('verkoopPrijs:') }}
    {{ Form::text('verkoopPrijs') }} <br>

    {{Form::label('Fabrieken', 'Fabrieken Id:') }}
    {{ Form::select('Fabrieken_Id', $fabrieks)}} <br>
    {{ Form::submit('edit')}}
    {{ Form::close() }}
```

if there is anything else that i need to add to the question just let me know and i'll add it

Comment: You have an argument in your function body, "Request $request, Product $product" from where it will take? how its passed in your defined route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing thing is the id you are not getting id there in your edit function
your edit function should as i am assuming that you are just showing the form from this method where user can edit

```
    public function edit($id)
{
       $product = Product::FindorFail($id);
       //Product is a table with all products, with sellprice and buy price
       //fabriek = table that has a foreign key attached to the product table
       return view('producten.edit', [
        'model' => $product,
        'fabrieks' => Fabriek::lists('Id')
        ]);

}
```

your update method should seem like this

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

    $product->update($request->all());

    return redirect(Route('producten.index'));

}
```

your routes should like this no need for only

```
Route::resource('/producten', 'productionController');
```

edit route will be as

```
<a href="{{ route('production.edit', $model->id) }}">
```

Try this hope it will help

Comment: i've changed 'action' => 'ProductenController@update' to 'Route' => 'Producten.update', $model->Id, and added the $id to the function, and it seems to work, but now i get a MethodNotAllowedHttpException error when i press the edit button, do u maby know how to fix it?

Comment: you not need to write route for update just write for edit and after that your data will be pass automatically to update where you can update as 
`<a href="{{ route('production.edit', $model->id) }}"> `

Comment: Is there any way to update form without passing record id in update route laravel? I don't want such that `/producten/1/edit` @ramzan-mahmood

Comment: @FaridVatani yes it is possible you can send id with hidden type , get it in controller and do what you wan to achieve

Comment: Can you give me an example? @ramzan-mahmood

Comment: @FaridVatani its the same way you get normal text parameter. in this case instead of type text change it to hidden in your form like `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="3487">`.  now simply get this parameter id in your controller.  ^°°^